# UML class diagram, agregation or composition with example

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I have short question about class diagrams. In my book we have class Person and class Gender and agregation arrow between them(with diamond pointing to person). Now, in general when I want to decide whether we have agregation or not I am using one of these two rules:
1.When you destroy class that is whole, than part can exist without it;
2.Class that is part in agregation relation, can be mutual to one or more wholes.

Now if we look at this example and rule number 2, it is OK, because one gender is mutual to one or more persons. But for the first one, if there is not person, than we can't talk about gender right?So I would set composition here. Probably I am missing main difference between these two. Any help is appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

### In general

Your rule about when using aggregation is not wrong.  But it's unnecessarily complex.  There is a simpler much simpler rule about when you'd better use aggregation:  ***never***.

This may sound provocative, but the hard truth is that the meaning of aggregation is not defined in the UML specifications, which makes it ambiguous and subject to a lot of unnecessary time-consuming debates:

> Sometimes a Property is used to model circumstances in which one instance is used to group together a set of instances; this is called aggregation. (...) Precise semantics of shared aggregation varies by application area and modeler.
> - UML specifications 2.5.1, page 112.

I know, it comes as a shock.  For years in my career, I have myself selected very carefully aggregation whenever there was a part-whole relation with non-exclusive ownership. But when I came accross James Rumbaugh famous quote, I challenged my own assumptions and realized how vain and subjective this quest was:

> Keep in mind that aggregation is association. Aggregation conveys the thought that the aggregate is inherently the sum of its parts. In fact, the only real semantics that it adds to association is the constraint that chains of aggregate links may not form cycle (...)  In spite of the few semantics attached to aggregation, everybody thinks it is necessary (for different reasons). Think of it as a [modeling placebo](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/AggregationAndComposition.html).
> - James Rumbaugh in *Unified Modeling Language Reference Manual*, chapter 14.

So, whenever you have aggregation in a model, you could simply replace it with an association without real loss of information.

### In your specific example

The association:  `Person ----- Gender`  expresses perfectly that a person has a gender, and that several persons can share the same gender.

If you want to be super-accurate,  you could use the [dot notation](https://www.omg.org/ocup-2/documents/getting_it_right_on_the_dot.pdf) (with a small dot on `Gender` side).  This would convey the information that `Person` owns the end of the association.

Composition would definitely be wrong here, because it's an exclusive ownership and no two persons could share the same gender.

Aggregation is ambigous:  what is the whole, what is the part? If gender is a part,  wouldn't character be a part as well.  And what with the name, then ?

A final remark:  if you want to implement this with `Person` having a `gender:Gender` property (an OOP mechanism called "[object composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition)") the, you don't need aggregation (even if it's a popular practice).